# python: while loops/flags: receiving a string and returns one float number with the average

Tags: python, flags

I need to define a function which receives a string (possibly containing digits, letters and/or special symbols) and returns one float number containing the average calculated considering all the digits in the string starting from the last position in the string and considering all digits (going backwards) until one letter is found or until reaching  the start of the string (and include the first character in the string for the calculation if it is a digit) . If there are no digits in the string, or if a letter is found before the first digit is found, then the function should return the value 0.0.

For example:

A function avgBackw("-1---2--A--3--4--") should return 3.5 because the average of 4 and 3 is 3.5. Notice that 1 and 2 do not enter in the calculation because visiting the string  backwards the letter A is found before visiting 2 and 1.

I can't seem to find out how to stop the calcualation when the letter "A" is found before going to 2 and 1.

Comment: Do you have any code to post so you we can see where it is going wrong?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This will do you homework for you:

```
def MyMean(myList): 
    rv = []  
    for n in myList[::-1] : # reverse list
        try:
            rv.append(int(n)) # convert element to int
        except:
            # 2.7: 
            return float(sum(rv))/len(rv) # on first error, bail and return number
            # 3.6
            # return sum(rv)/len(rv) # all numbers need to return as well

    # 2.7: 
    return float(sum(rv))/len(rv)  # on first error, bail and return number
    # 3.6 
    # return sum(rv)/len(rv) # all numbers need to return as well


myLis = [1,2,4,'A',3,4]

print(MyMean(myLis))

myLis = "1239A9391"

print(MyMean(myLis))

myLis = "1020392"

print(MyMean(myLis))
```

Output:

```
# 2.7 
3.5
5.5
2.42857142857

#3.6
3.5
5.5
2.4285714285714284
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for some reason... seems to be a problem with the rv.append

Comment: @s.wang You are probably on Python 2.7 - fixed it so it now should work for 2.7 and 3.6